# Cordova call JavaScript function from Java without webview

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

How can we call JavaScript function from Java. For example i have sayHello function which is in www/js/app.js. I need to write a method in java which will call this sayHello and give result back using cordova.

```
 sayHello: function(name) {
    return "Hello "+name;
}
```

Comment: what you want isn't possible, you need the webview to execute the javascript. It's not neccesary that you show it, but you have to use it to execute javascript

Comment: @jcesarmobile - cordova creates a webview, so there is one to use. the question is how to actually achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//method to exec javascript
private static synchronized void executeJavascript(final String strJS, CordovaWebView myWebView) {

    Runnable jsLoader = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + strJS);
        }
    };
    try {
        Method post = myWebView.getClass().getMethod("post",Runnable.class);
        post.invoke(myWebView,jsLoader);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        ((Activity)(myWebView.getContext())).runOnUiThread(jsLoader);
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a class

```
public class MyCordovaPlugin extends CordovaPlugin
```

You would have a method

```
@Override
public void initialize (CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
      //and call your method
      executeJavascript("sayHello('bear')", webView);
}
```

Comment: your executeJavascript method requires 2 params and you only send one, how do you get the webview then?

Comment: Edited my answer. You might want to have a look on how to create Cordova plugins.

Comment: I know how to create cordova plugins, just wanted to let you know that your answer was wrong. This one seems better

Comment: But how can i receive call back from JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

Finally i got.

we need to create java script interface for call back to java. Here is my complete code.

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(mActivity, "callBack");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("javascript: sayHello('yourName'));

@JavascriptInterface
public void helloResult(String value) {
   Log.v("Result",name);
}
```

and script.

```
 sayHello: function(name) {
    callBack.helloResult("Hello "+name);
}
```